# Admob interstitial ad latency issues when loading ad

Tags: android, admob

I am trying to implement interstitial ad in a fragment, when button is clicked the fragment doesn't open other activity , but loads data in same fragment so i can't use the they way people say interstisial ad should be used when navigating between activities. instead i am using the ad for only once when button is clicked .it works but takes sometime .how to deal with it?

it only works if user pressed the button after few seconds of launching the app.

```
   public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        
        root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);


             Button btn=root.findViewById(R.id.btn);
                    
                    

             initAds();
            
            
             btn.setOnClickListener(this);
            
            return root;
    }  
    
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view){
        
        initAdsCallBack();
    }

 private void initAds(){
       
        MobileAds.initialize(requireActivity(), new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationComplete(@NonNull InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {

               createNonPersonalisedAd();
            }
        });
    }

    }
    private void createNonPersonalisedAd() {

        Bundle networkExtrasBundle = new Bundle();
        networkExtrasBundle.putInt("rdp", 1);
        AdManagerAdRequest adRequest = (AdManagerAdRequest) new AdManagerAdRequest.Builder()
                .addNetworkExtrasBundle(AdMobAdapter.class, networkExtrasBundle)
                .build();
        createInterstitialAd(adRequest);
    }
    private  void createInterstitialAd(AdRequest adRequest){


        AdManagerInterstitialAd.load(requireActivity(),getResources().getString(R.string.str_iterstitial), (AdManagerAdRequest) adRequest,
                new AdManagerInterstitialAdLoadCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAdLoaded(@NonNull AdManagerInterstitialAd interstitialAd) {
                        // The mAdManagerInterstitialAd reference will be null until
                        // an ad is loaded.
                        mAdManagerInterstitialAd = interstitialAd;
                        Log.i(TAG, "onAdLoaded");

                        ///// best place to callback is here coz its successfully loaded here
                        mAdManagerInterstitialAd.setFullScreenContentCallback(new FullScreenContentCallback(){
                            @Override
                            public void onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
                                // Called when fullscreen content is dismissed.
                                Log.d("TAG", "The ad was dismissed.");
                                createInterstitialAd(adRequest);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(AdError adError) {
                                // Called when fullscreen content failed to show.
                                Log.d("TAG", "The ad failed to show.");
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onAdShowedFullScreenContent() {
                                // Called when fullscreen content is shown.
                                // Make sure to set your reference to null so you don't
                                // show it a second time.
                                mAdManagerInterstitialAd = null;
                                Log.d("TAG", "The ad was shown.");
                            }
                        });
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAdFailedToLoad(@NonNull LoadAdError loadAdError) {
                        // Handle the error
                        Log.i(TAG, loadAdError.getMessage());
                        mAdManagerInterstitialAd = null;
                    }
                });


    }

    private void initAdsCallBack(){

     
                if (mAdManagerInterstitialAd != null) {

                    mAdManagerInterstitialAd.show(requireActivity());
                    debugToast("ad shown");
                } else {
                         Log.e("Tad didn't show");
                         
                }
            
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider **pre-loading** your interstitial ads to reduce latency when displaying them to your users. For more information about pre-loading your interstitial ads refer to the AdMob Interstitial Ad developer guidelines for apps developed for [Android](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/interstitial)